# Pandas Merge without overwriting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. I am trying to merge data from DF1 to DF2 without altering any of the previously existing data in DF2.

```
DF1 = 
Value    Color
0         Red
1         White
2         Blue

DF2 = 
Value    Color
0         
1         
2         Brown
3         Black
4         White
5         

DF3 = pd.merge(DF2, DF1, on="Value", how='left', suffixes=('_x', '')).drop(['Color_x'], axis=1)
```

Current Result: It overwrites data that already exists. For example it correctly overwrites Brown to Blue. However, it also removes Black and White since those values do not exist in DF1. I want it just to merge or overwrite where the Value we're merging on matches.

```
DF3 = 
Value    Color
0         Red
1         White
2         Blue
3         
4         
5
```

Expected Result:

```
DF3 = 
Value    Color
0         Red
1         White
2         Blue
3         Black
4         White
5
```

Comment: Are those empty strings or a `null` value recognized by pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you look for `update`

```
df2.update(df1)

print(df2)

Out[253]:
   Value  Color
0  0.0    Red
1  1.0    White
2  2.0    Blue
3  3.0    Black
4  4.0    White
5  5.0
```

---

**Note**: this answer bases on your sample data where `df1` index or `value` is subset of `df2`. You don't mention about index, so I assume it is default `rangeindex`. If index isn't rangeindex, you need `set_index` on `value`

```
df2 = df2.set_index('Value')
df2.update(df1.set_index('Value'))
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

Comment: @ALollz: yes, you are right. I added the note to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

We can using `combine_first`

```
df1.set_index('Value').combine_first(df2.set_index('Value')).reset_index()
   Value  Color
0      0    Red
1      1  White
2      2   Blue
3      3  Black
4      4  White
5      5    NaN
```